# check for empty in jstl if tag

Tags: jstl

My code to iterate list and show the rows

```
<c:if test="${not empty ftp}">
    <c:forEach var="event" items="${ftp}">
                <tr><td><input type="text" name="hostName" id="hostName" value="${event.hostName}"size="30" maxlength="200"/></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="directory" id="directory" value="${event.directory}" size="30" maxlength="200"/></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="userName" id="userName" value="${event.userName}" size="20" maxlength="20"/></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="password" id="password" value="${event.password}" size="20" maxlength="20" onblur="checkEnableButton();"/></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="delete" onclick="if(confirm( 'Do you want to delete')) deleteRow(this);" value="-" /></td></tr>
            </c:forEach>
</c:if>
```

this works good..but, if my list is empty I need to show a blank row..? and what should I do, if I want to delete and add rows dynamicaaly from JSP page..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current use of `<c:if test="${not empty ftp}">...</c:if>` can be removed, since the `forEach` loop will also do the same check and skip any processing if it is indeed empty.

As for displaying a row if empty, you could just do something like:

```
<c:if test="${empty ftp}">
    ...display empty table row here...
</c:if>
```

If you're wanting to do things dynamically, you will need to develop some JavaScript. JSTL is done on the server, but JavaScript will allow you to do dynamic client side processing.

Comment: thank you..i have javascript to add and delete rows dynamically..but, how to pass the data from dynamic rows to db?

Comment: Sounds like you want to post that data via ajax to a servlet or something listening on your server.